# Not working QPushButton

Tags: qt

In my QMainWindow class, i have another class named MyDialog that inherits from qdialog. In there i redefine my MyDialog as following:

```
MyDialog en = new MyDialog(this);
```

inwhich I have inserted a qpushbutton named myButton; i wrote this code in my MyDialog constructor to use that button

```
connect(ui.myButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(this->do_Method()));
```

and the slot do_Method() function is bit strange. Every time I click on myButton it runs not do_Method(). 
What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove your this:

```
connect(ui.myButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(do_Method()));
```

Comment: I asume you already set Q_OBJECT and added:<br>    private slots:
     void do_Method();

Comment: >moc: Too many input files specified
>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from “Moc’ing QPButtonTest.h…”
====== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ======

Comment: Try to moc it manually again by means of “moc.exe QPButtonTest.h -o moc_QPButtonTest.cxx” and add that moc_QPButtonTest.cxx to your project (Add --> Existing Item..).

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
connect( ui.myButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( do_Method() ) );
```